# Why does $M_0(\omega)\in\{0,1\}$ imply $M_0=0$ or M_0=1$ almost surely here?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A),(E,\mathcal E)$ be measurable spaces, $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$, $(M_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $[0,1]$-valued $\mathcal F^X$-adapted process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$, $\theta_t:\Omega\to\Omega$ for $t\ge0$ with $$M_{s+t}=M_s(M_t\circ\theta_s)\tag1$$ for all $s,t\ge0$, $\operatorname P_x$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with $\operatorname P_x[X_0=x]=1$ for $x\in E$ and $$E_M:=\{x\in E:\operatorname P_x[M_0=1]=1\}.$$

> How do we show that $\operatorname P_x[M_0=1]=0$ for all $x\in E\setminus E_M$?

Clearly, $(1)$ implies $M_0=M_0^2$ and hence $$M_0(\omega)\in\{0,1\}\;\;\;\text{for all }\omega\in\Omega\tag2.$$ But the only thing I get from $x\in E\setminus E_M$ is $\operatorname P_x[M_0=1]<1$ ...

The claim is made (in a more involved setting) in [General Theory of Markov Processes](https://books.google.com/books?id=lMpIvtIgFiMC&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267&dq=%22Exactly+Subordinate+Semigroups%22&source=bl&ots=xlvBtgXDzD&sig=ACfU3U1QUV7yLXizvcyGM7zqV88zTnYGiA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdy8znlf_3AhXmSvEDHXN3AqUQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Exactly%20Subordinate%20Semigroups%22&f=false) below equation (56.1). Maybe I'm missing a crucial assumption to infer the claim.

Comment: If $\theta$ is the identity, $M_0$ satisfies (2), then $M_t=M_0$ for all $t$ satisfies (1). Indeed, there seems to be something missing. (If I understand everything correctly)

Comment: You have to distinguish between '$M_0=0$ or $M_0=1$ almost surely'  and '$M_0=0$  almost surely or $M_0=1$ almost surely'.

Comment: @daw Please take note of my edit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I've actually got that phrase wrong. I*ve described in the setting in the book more precisely. There is still something unclear to me.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out. $\operatorname P_x[X_0=x]=1$ implies that $\sigma(X_0)$ is $\operatorname P$-trivial. Since $M_0$ is $\sigma(X_0)$-measurable, $\sigma(M_0)$ is $\operatorname P$-trivial as well. So, without the need of using $(2)$, we immediately obtain $\operatorname P_x[M_0=1]=0$ (for all $x\in E\setminus E_M$).